# Worksheet Editor bringing last character to newline when typing too fast

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When i'm writing sql in sql developer and typing out a query quickly and do a new line, it'll bring the last character over to the new line and put my cursor behind the character.

```sql
SELECT *

SELECT
//cursor is here *
```

Comment: OS? Version of SQLDev? Version of Java? Look and feel (Native OS or Oracle?) Have you tried typing not so fast...how fast is fast?

Comment: I did a bit more experimenting and it seems to happen only on the first line and it depends on how fast i press enter after typing the last character of the first line. If i just wait a second or two this doesn't seem to happen. Operating system is windows 10 P. Newest version of SQLDev on oracle's site and the java developer kit that comes with it. Happened in both native OS and oracle ui. There were a couple of other things that slightly annoyed me as well, so I just swapped over to DBeaver for now.

Comment: >>There were a couple of other things that slightly annoyed me as well...Like what? if you're interested in getting things fixed, feel free to share jeff.d.smith@oracle.com